# Mono on Artik710

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I have a problem with getting Mono to work on Artik710. I installed the package "mono-devel" of fedora 24 and DNF says that everything is ok.
But when I try to compile a minimum "Hello world" program with mcs, I get a segmentation fault.
Also, when I compile the program on a PC and just try to run it on the Artik710 with "mono hello.exe", I also get a segmentation fault.
Just "mono -V" works and says:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.4 (tarball Thu Jun 23 19:09:56 UTC 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       normal
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

I assume that this problem caused by running 32-bit OS (and so 32-bit Mono) on 64-bit Cortex A-53 core processor. So the question is - is there any way to install (or build from source code) x64 Mono on 32-bit OS and is there any chanсe that it will work? Or problem with anything else? Here is some stack trace from gdb running Hello world program (not very helpful):

```
[New Thread 0xf6bff440 (LWP 4925)]  
[New Thread 0xf7123440 (LWP 4926)]

Thread 1 "mono" received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.  
0xf71b1b04 in ?? ()  
(gdb) continue  
Continuing.

Thread 1 "mono" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.  
0xf75e608c in strchrnul () from /lib/libc.so.6  
(gdb) continue  
Continuing.

Thread 1 "mono" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.  
0xf75e608c in strchrnul () from /lib/libc.so.6  
(gdb) continue  
Continuing.

Unable to fetch general registers.: No such process.  
Unable to fetch general registers.: No such process.  
Unable to fetch general registers.: No such process.  
(gdb) [Thread 0xf7123440 (LWP 4926) exited]  
[Thread 0xf6bff440 (LWP 4925) exited]

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.  
The program no longer exists.

The program is not being run.
```

Thanks for any help!

Notes:

Under valgrind tool debug my "Hello world" program actualy works in mono. So if I run "mono /root/Release/HelloWorldArtik.exe" - it returns only "Segmentation failed (core dumped)". But if I run "valgrind --tool=memcheck -v --leak-check=full --smc-check=all mono /root/Release/HelloWorldArtik.exe", the return is:

```
--2632-- Contents of /proc/version:
--2632-- Linux version 4.4.71-0710GC0F-44F-01QC (release@iotadmin-PowerEdge-T630) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jul 13 19:58:14 KST 2017
--2632-- Arch and hwcaps: ARM, LittleEndian, ARMv7-neon-vfp
--2632-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--2632-- Reading syms from /usr/bin/mono-sgen
--2632--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/03/d41817d1bf496a1e9fbb96dcbaf91dca2f2a36.debug ..
--2632--   .. build-id is valid
--2632--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/be/69fde943ee25e3d503d6e9298eca48dfbb1696.debug ..
--2632--   .. build-id is valid
--2632-- Warning: cross-CU LIMITATION: some inlined fn names
--2632-- might be shown as UnknownInlinedFun
--2632-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/ld-2.23.so
--2632--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/ld-2.23.so.debug ..
--2632--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 8c51544a wanted a0a8f5fa)
--2632--   Reading EXIDX entries: 147 available
==2632==   Warning: whilst reading EXIDX: ExtabEntryDecode: failed with error code: -10
==2632==   Warning: whilst reading EXIDX: ExtabEntryDecode: failed with error code: -10
(a lot of same warnings and redirections)
Reading EXIDX entries: 2018 attempted, 1836 successful
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49df1c0 (libc.so.6:memcpy) redirected to 0x4831690 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49deec0 (libc.so.6:memset) redirected to 0x484df08 (memset)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49e75c0 (libc.so.6:__memcpy_neon) redirected to 0x484be9c (memcpy)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49dd5f0 (libc.so.6:rindex) redirected to 0x4849a4c (rindex)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49dd241 (libc.so.6:strlen) redirected to 0x484a23c (strlen)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49dc8b1 (libc.so.6:strcmp) redirected to 0x484b48c (strcmp)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49dd464 (libc.so.6:strncmp) redirected to 0x484ab74 (strncmp)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49dc7c0 (libc.so.6:index) redirected to 0x4849c9c (index)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49de5b1 (libc.so.6:memchr) redirected to 0x484b75c (memchr)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49e104c (libc.so.6:strchrnul) redirected to 0x484e8e0 (strchrnul)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49d6f58 (libc.so.6:malloc) redirected to 0x48464f8 (malloc)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49d72b8 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4847b38 (free)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49d7978 (libc.so.6:calloc) redirected to 0x4848c40 (calloc)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49dd5a0 (libc.so.6:strncpy) redirected to 0x484a634 (strncpy)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49d7394 (libc.so.6:realloc) redirected to 0x4848eac (realloc)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49dcbc0 (libc.so.6:strcpy) redirected to 0x484a3fc (strcpy)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49dc79c (libc.so.6:strcat) redirected to 0x4849ddc (strcat)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49deb80 (libc.so.6:memmove) redirected to 0x484dfd0 (memmove)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49ddf74 (libc.so.6:strstr) redirected to 0x484f254 (strstr)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49e0fc0 (libc.so.6:rawmemchr) redirected to 0x484e918 (rawmemchr)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49dd31c (libc.so.6:strnlen) redirected to 0x484a184 (strnlen)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49dcbb0 (libc.so.6:stpcpy) redirected to 0x484d72c (stpcpy)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49df0bc (libc.so.6:strcasecmp_l) redirected to 0x484b0b4 (strcasecmp_l)
--2632-- REDIR: 0x49de64c (libc.so.6:bcmp) redirected to 0x484d5b4 (bcmp)
--2632-- memcheck GC: 1000 nodes, 0 survivors (0.0%)
Hello, world! From Artik 710 (this is program output)
==2632==
==2632== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2632==     in use at exit: 12,271 bytes in 330 blocks
==2632==   total heap usage: 44,241 allocs, 43,911 frees, 15,597,707 bytes allocated
==2632==
==2632== Searching for pointers to 330 not-freed blocks
==2632== Checked 23,350,064 bytes
==2632==
==2632== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 297
==2632==    at 0x4846584: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==2632==    by 0x336A43: monoeg_malloc (gmem.c:73)
==2632==    by 0x25958F: mono_metadata_type_dup (metadata.c:5048)
==2632==    by 0x1BB0AF: get_shared_gparam (mini-generic-sharing.c:2850)
==2632==    by 0x1BB2EF: UnknownInlinedFun (mini-generic-sharing.c:2915)
==2632==    by 0x1BB2EF: get_shared_inst.isra.15 (mini-generic-sharing.c:2939)
==2632==    by 0x1BD117: mini_get_shared_method_full (mini-generic-sharing.c:2997)
==2632==    by 0x132943: lookup_method (mini-runtime.c:1763)
==2632==    by 0x1329EB: mono_jit_compile_method_with_opt (mini-runtime.c:1868)
==2632==    by 0x133437: mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:2179)
==2632==    by 0x2ABA7B: mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2783)
==2632==    by 0x2ABF23: mono_runtime_class_init_full (object.c:367)
==2632==    by 0x15CF67: mono_method_to_ir (method-to-ir.c:11237)
(and so on)

 LEAK SUMMARY:
 ==2632==    definitely lost: 746 bytes in 29 blocks
 ==2632==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==2632==      possibly lost: 288 bytes in 2 blocks
 ==2632==    still reachable: 11,237 bytes in 299 blocks
 ==2632==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==2632== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
 ==2632== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
 ==2632==
 ==2632== ERROR SUMMARY: 22 errors from 22 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
 ==2632== ERROR SUMMARY: 22 errors from 22 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Could someone please clarify for me, what all of this means?

Answer (score 0):

Use valgrind tool to check for invalid read and write .This will give you proper information.